# Navigation bar Bug while Sliding ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a View Controller which is the 2nd View Controller and need a navigation bar. The 1st one is a controller which doesn't need a Nav Bar and 3rd View Controller need a navigation bar.

As per stacks 3rd view controller will be no top of stack.

I have implemented these methods in 2nd View Controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Quikr_Util.colorWithHexString("#0083cb")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }
}
```

The things were working fine if a use a `back` bar button to go back from 3rd to 2nd View Controller.

Things got messy when I started to slide from one View Controller to another for example, when I slide half and then release.

It means sliding from 3rd to 2nd but release in between so it goes to 3rd View Controller rather than second .

What may be the best way to hide and unhide view navigation bars .

Secondly, how do sliding works , which functions will get called when sliding happens?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "things got messy?"

Answer (score 0):

For your first question

To hide and show the Navigation Controller, in **2nd and 3rd** View Controllers, You can use:

- Hide:

  ```
  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
  ```
- Show:

  ```
  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
  ```

There is not really a need to check if it is hidden or not.

For the second question, you can use UIGestureRecognizer

Edit: 
Just to be clear, instead of hiding and showing the in the same file, hide and show in `viewDidAppear()` in needed swift files

Comment: of two different view controllers files

Comment: I tried to do that , I hide the nav bar in viewdidload of 2nd view controller and In 3rd I Show it again. Then when i press back , I can see the bar again in 2nd view controller .

Comment: Should i place in viewDidAppear() of every View Controller ?

Comment: For each one that you have a change in. if you hide in VC2, you will need to show in VC1 and VC3